# FB.ui 'share' не обрабатывает параметры

Tags: share

Добрый день, использую sdk facebook, конкретно метод "share"

```
 FB.ui(
        {
            method: 'share',
            href: 'url to site',     
            title: 'dddd',  
            picture: 'urltoimage',
            caption: 'w3e24324',
            description: 'descrisretetption',
        },
        function(response){
            // your code to manage the response
        });
```

естественно, вместо "рыбы" в значениях параметров стоят реальные данные.
В итоге, появляется попап, но не цепляется ничего (ни  описание, ни картинка) кроме названия домена (даже не конкретная страница, которая указана в "href"). Что не так?

Answer (score 1):

Нашла решение! Поменяла версию (version) с 2.9 на 2.7

```
 FB.init({
        appId      : '************',
        status     : true,
        version    : 'v2.7'
    });
```